# How to send data from route to component?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am beginner to ember.

I want to send data from route to component.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
var model = null;
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return true;
    }
});
```

i have defined this model in route now i want to use this model in component js file. i have just do console log but it gives undefined.
my component js code is below

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement() {
        console.log(model);
    }
});
```

So can anyone suggest what is the actual way to use data of route in component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just return the data you need to pass it to template,

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        //here return model data which requires to display template
        return true;
    }
});
```

Inside template you can access is using `model`, in this case you just sent true so your `model` will contains `true`.

You need to pass this model to component so that you can access it from component. 
Inside template.hbs,

```
{{my-component model=model }}
```

You can access model property in component,

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement() {
        console.log('Model ',this.get('model'));
    }
});
```

Welcome to Ember. I am strongly encouraging you to read [ember guides](http://guides.emberjs.com) and play with [ember-twiddle](http://ember-twiddle.com)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the data to component from template; that is from route's template you need to pass whatever you want (i.e. model) to corresponding model. See the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/0611474819d2e8b9be763a4e009d9239?openFiles=templates.components.my-component.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs) for a simple demonstration.

In this example; `index` route returns a json object (an object with name & surname fields) from the `model` hook. What is returned from this model hook is passed to `my-component` inside `index.hbs` template file as `object` property. Then you can access the corresponding data within component's js and hbs files easily. In the example; data is shown within `my-component.hbs` template file. Hope it is clear.